# Javascript - Is there a better way to split a string based on its length?

Tags: javascript, string

I have the time of day in strings ie. (830, 1450, 1630). I know I can do simple if statements to check if the length is 3 or 4 and get out (8) and (30) or (14) and (50), but is there a cleaner way to split the hour and the minute without having to check in if statements?

Comment: a regular expression? padStart and substr ?

Comment: Why dont you just add a 0 if length is 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) offers an easy way to do this, because negative numbers are interpreted as from the end of the string.

```js
minutes = s.slice(-2)    // last two characters of s
hours = s.slice(0, -2)   // from first character up to but not including last two characters
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way with [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), though the syntax looks a little weird.

```
/^(\d{1,2})(\d{2})$/
/                  /    starts/stops regex definition
 ^                      matches from the start of the string (not a random middle location)
  (       )(     )      match two groups
   \d                   a digit...
     {1,2}              that needs to exist 1 or 2 times
            \d          a digit...
              {2}       that needs to exist two times
```

Used in code, it would look something like this:

```js
const times = ["830", "1520", "1015"];
const regex = /^(\d{1,2})(\d{2})$/;

const extractTime = (s) => s.match(regex).slice(1, 3);

times.map(extractTime).forEach(([hours, minutes]) => console.log({
  hours,
  minutes
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your time will always be represented in HH:mm, you can pad the string and then slice the parts.

```
const parseTime = (time: string): [string, string] => {
   const timePadded = time.padStart(4, 0)
   return [timePadded.slice(0, 2), timePadded.slice(2, 4)]
}

parseTime("830") # ["08", "30"]
parseTime("1430") # ["14", "30"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = [830, 1450, 1630];

a.forEach((item) => {
  console.log('Hour = ' + ('0' + item).slice(-4).substring(0, 2) + ' Minute = ' + item.toString().slice(-2));
});

a.forEach((item) => {
  console.log('Hour = ' + ('0' + item).slice(-4, -2) + ' Minute = ' + item.toString().slice(-2));
});
```